# How does one travel across the Death Star?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, death-star

How does a human (humanoid) travel across the Death Star, which is way bigger than any of the Imperial Navy Vessels (Death Star I was 120km in diameter, DS2 was even larger - 200km). Let us say that an officer is ordered to travel to another sector to check on workers activity there. How can this be achieved in a reasonable amount of time?

I do not remember seeing any lifts, trams or anything like that in the movies, but perhaps it is covered in the books?

Legends or Canon answers are accepted.

Inspired by [this question.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236644/how-do-you-get-from-one-end-of-a-super-star-destroyer-to-the-other)

Comment: In fact turbolifts *are* seen in the movie, when Luke and Han take Chewie to the detention level. That only showed vertical travel, though.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 - Given that gravity is controlled locally, that turbolift could have been moving in any direction

Comment: _Very carefully._

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the *[Death Star Technical Companion](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Death_Star_Technical_Companion)*.

> **Turbolift Cluster Station**
>
> One couldn’t walk more than a few bundled meters without bumping into
> some kind of turbolift conveyance, but even more impressive were the
> scores upon scores of turbolift cluster stations found all over the
> battle station. The turbolift conveyance system made use of the most
> common form of technology available in the galaxy, repulsorlift field
> generators. By filling long stretches of cylindrical shafts with
> repulsor fields, the designers created a travel system that connected
> all portions of the Death Star. **Turbolift cars reach incredible speeds
> within a repulsor field, covering many kilometers per minute. They
> also performed the much-needed tack of gravity transition orientation
> through the use of gravity compensators and rotating cars.**
>
> Turbolift cars were activated by voice command. Repulsor shafts
> crisscrossed the massive battle station in all directions, and all
> shafts connected somewhere within the Death Star. **If a crewman entered
> a turbolift anywhere on the battle station, he could have directed it
> to take him to any other location aboard the Death Star.** Turbolifts
> extended into the surface city sprawls, but **even with the large
> number of cars available and the great speeds that they reached, it
> was often faster and more convenient to take a shuttle from one hangar
> bay to a bay nearer the final destination.**

The [Death Star Owner's Technical Manual](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Death_Star_Owner%27s_Technical_Manual) also offers a plan view of the major arterial turbolift channels.

[image]

Comment: "Here you go, Grand Moff, here's the Owner's Manual" "Owner's Manual! I don't have time reading that thing! Darth!" ... Of course, as everyone is aware, _HAD_ he read the damned thing, the Rebellion wouldn't have succeeded...

Comment: @CGCampbell - Tarkin built it and would already know everything in the manual. I'm not really sure who the target audience is supposed to be. Probably the next guy along.